# How to dynamically allocate parameter value

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am new to API usage, and I am trying to allocate the value dynamically.
Basically, I will be asking user to input the parameter value, and I want to use that value as the parameter.Instead of me hardcoding the value provided by the user.

Here's a snippet of how I am hardcoding the API parameter value.

```
response = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/players/365247625/wordcloud")
```

You may use  "365247625" as the value to send dynamically instead of hardcoding as I did above.

Comment: I don't get your question. You mean you want to get a parameter from user like `365247625` and then get a api url corresponding to that input?

Comment: the value 365247625 is hardcoded by myself. What I want is that this value should be entered by the user and automatically add itself to the parameter value in API. I hope I have cleared my self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can ask user for a value using `input()`
2. Then you can dynamically put this value into a string by executing string's `.format()` method which replaces `{}` with the argument:

```
val = input()
response = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/players/{}/wordcloud".format(val))
```